# Input to the Neural Network using an array

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am writing a neural network to take the Mel frequency coefficients as inputs and then run the model. My dataset contains 100 samples - each sample is an array of 12 values corresponding to the coefficients. After splitting this data into train and test sets, I have created the X input corresponding to the array and the y input corresponding to the label.

[Data array containing the coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e52v.png)

Here is a small sample of my data containing 5 elements in the X_train array:

['[107.59366    -14.153783    24.799461    -8.244417    20.95272\n  -4.375943    12.77285     -0.92922235   3.9418116    7.3581047\n  -0.30066165   5.441765  ]'
'[ 96.49664     2.0689797  21.557552  -32.827045    7.348135  -23.513977\n   7.9406714 -16.218931   10.594619  -21.4381      0.5903044 -10.569035 ]'
'[105.98041    -2.0483367  12.276348  -27.334534    6.8239    -23.019623\n   7.5176797 -21.884727   11.349695  -22.734652    3.0335162 -11.142375 ]'
'[ 7.73094559e+01  1.91073620e+00  6.72225571e+00 -2.74525508e-02\n  6.60858107e+00  5.99264860e-01  1.96265772e-01 -3.94772577e+00\n  7.46383286e+00  5.42239428e+00  1.21432066e-01  2.44894314e+00]']

When I create the Neural network, I want to use the 12 coefficients as an input for the network. In order to do this, I need to use each row of my X_train dataset that contains these arrays as the input. However, when I try to consider the array index as an input it gives me shape errors when trying to fit the model. My model is as follows:

```
def build_model_graph():
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(12,)))
model.add(Dense(12))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_labels))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
return model
```

Here, I want to use every row of the X_train array as an input which would correspond to the shape(12,). When I use something like this:

```
num_epochs = 50
num_batch_size = 32
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=num_batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, 
validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```

I get an error for the shape which makes sense to me.
For reference, the error is as follows:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_20" (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "dense_54" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
```

But I am not exactly sure how I can extract the array of 12 coefficients present at each index of the X_train and then use it in the model input. Indexing the x_train and y_train did not work either. If anyone could point me in a relevant direction, it would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Edit: My code for the dataframe is as follows:

```
clapdf = pd.read_csv("clapsdf.csv")
clapdf.drop('Unnamed: 0', inplace=True, axis=1)
clapdf.head()
nonclapdf = pd.read_csv("nonclapsdf.csv")
nonclapdf.drop('Unnamed: 0', inplace=True, axis=1)
sound_df = clapdf.append(nonclapdf)
sound_df.head()
d=sound_data.tolist()
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data = df[0].to_numpy()
print("Before-->", data.shape)
dat = np.array([np.array(d) for d in data])
print('After-->', dat.shape)
```

Here, the shape remains the same as the values of each of the 80 samples are not in a comma separated format but instead in the form of a series.

Comment: post some small sample of your data in order to make the error replicable

Comment: if the data is a string and elements are delimited by spaces, you could split on spaces and then cast every element to integer

Comment: Can you confirm that the type of your elements is string? if not, which type do you get using type(sample)

Comment: I think the issue is arising from the y_train - as the x_train contains numeric values but the y_train is a string describing the label of the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data looks like this:

```py
samples = 2
features = 12
x_train = tf.random.normal((samples, 1, features))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[-2.5988803  -0.629626   -0.8306641  -0.78226614  0.88989156
   -0.3851106  -0.66053045  1.0571191  -0.59061646 -1.1602987
    0.69124466 -0.04354193]]

 [[-0.86917496  2.2923143  -0.05498986 -0.09578358  0.85037625
   -0.54679644 -1.2213608  -1.3766612   0.35416105 -0.57801914
   -0.3699728   0.7884727 ]]], shape=(2, 1, 12), dtype=float32)
```

You will have to reshape it to `(2, 12)` in order to fit your model with the input shape `(batch_size, 12)`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def build_model_graph():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(12,)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(12))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))
  # Compile the model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
  return model

model = build_model_graph()

samples = 2
features = 12
x_train = tf.random.normal((samples, 1, features))
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train, (samples, features))
y = tf.random.uniform((samples, 1), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, 2)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=2)
```

Also, you usually need to convert your labels to one-hot encoded vectors if you plan to use `categorical_crossentropy`.
`y_train` looks like this:

```
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

***Update 1:***
If your data is coming from a dataframe, try something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'features': [[0.18525402, 0.92130125, 0.2296906,  0.75818471, 0.69813222, 0.47147329,
                   0.03560711, 0.06583931, 0.90921289, 0.76002148, 0.50413995, 0.36099004], 
                  [0.18525402, 0.92130125, 0.2296906,  0.75818471, 0.69813222, 0.47147329,
                   0.03560711, 0.06583931, 0.90921289, 0.76002148, 0.50413995, 0.36099004]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

data = df['features'].to_numpy()
print('Before -->', data.shape)
data = np.array([np.array(d) for d in data])
print('After -->', data.shape)
```

```
Before --> (2,)
After --> (2, 12)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, I do use the encoding for the labels. My shapes for all the train and test arrays are as follows: X_train ->(80,) ; X_test ->(20,) ; Y_train->(80, 2) ; Y_test->(20, 2). In each of these 80 and 20 entries for X and Y train respectively, the values stored are an array of 12 numbers - these numbers are what I want to pass as the input to the model. So, while your suggestion does work out in a usual scenario - the reshaping for me gives an issue as I can only reshape the dimensions of the X and the Y but I need the 12 values present at each index of the X and Y sets.

Comment: Updated answer. Did it work ?

Comment: Hey, I am trying it out. There is some issue with how the data is being identified. I am combining two dataframes to create my final dataframe - when I do this, the final dataframe contains 80 samples which has 12 values in one sample but those values are not in a comma separated format. So when I pass them through a loop, the shape remains the same. I am working on keeping the array in a format where I can modify the shape as given in the solution

Comment: Are the arrays space-separated?

Comment: Yes, it is now a numpy array and only separated by spaces instead of commas - but the shape remains the same in the before and after operation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240180/discussion-between-siddhant-yeole-and-alonetogether).